# Exception loading model for variant testmod:ruby#inventory for item "testmod:ruby", normal location exception:

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

[12:06:39] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant testmod:ruby#inventory for item "testmod:ruby", normal location exception:
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model testmod:item/ruby with loader VanillaLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:297) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:160) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:559) [Minecraft.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421) [Minecraft.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: testmod:models/item/ruby.json
at net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:69) ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:65) ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModel(ModelBakery.java:334) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.access$1600(ModelLoader.java:126) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:860) ~[ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
... 20 more
[12:06:39] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant testmod:ruby#inventory for item "testmod:ruby", blockstate location exception:
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model testmod:ruby#inventory with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:305) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:160) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:559) [Minecraft.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421) [Minecraft.class:?]
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:83) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1169) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
... 20 more

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: testmod:models/item/ruby.json

It cannot find `ruby.json`, the file doesn't exist. Make sure the file exists and also read the [documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.13.x/models/using/#item-models) on creating models.

Side note, take a look at the help guides on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).